# what is create_engine() doing in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

My goal is to push pandas dataframe to redshift. One of the stackoverflow question suggested to use following code to directly convert dataframe to redshift(saving effort of converting file to a csv and then running a copy command)

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import createengine
conn = create_engine('postgresql://fin:password@yoururl.com:8192/yourdatabase')
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2], 'col2': ['A','B']}
df.to_sql('tablename', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

Just inserting these two rows takes 35.47 seconds which is super slow.
I am trying to understand the reason for this being too slow. I came across following terms while going over articles.
1. ORM- more like translation layer between object oriented language to a table.
2. engine- in context of databases it is software used by a DBMS to perform CRUD operations.
3. driver- software used to connect to a dbms.
My questions are:
1. Is sqlalchemy creating a separate engine to my local and then pushing it to redshift using psycopg2 driver?
2. If not then what could be the reason of it being slow. Few articles mentioned that it inserts one rows at a time even then when i run `insert into mytablename values(1,'A')` it finishes in less than 1-2 seconds. So twice the rows should be ~4 seconds.
3. Since the ORM layer converts python commands to sql executable commands there would definitely be additional time required compared to if i use sql query via pycopg2(or pg8000 in my case). But does this mean it takes 25-30 seconds to just convert python objects to sql executable query?

Comment: Add `echo=True` to your `create_engine()` call to get a better idea of what is going on in the background when you run your code.

Comment: It works thank you so much. It seems my `if_exist='replace'` tag lead to execute of queries to check permissions, visibility to users etc hence increasing the time. Without it the time reduces from from ~35+ to <6 seconds.